# How do I move the second word BEFORE the first?

Tags: python, string

If my variable is:

```
string = "first second"
```

How can I change that to print:

```
second first
```

annoyingly simple but I can't find a solution for it!

Comment: Please post any code which you have tried and you will get a better response.

Comment: Also, it would be good to read over [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: Simple:   reversed = ' '.join(s.split(' ')[::-1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd split the string on `' '` and then join it back:

```
s = 'first second'
tmp = s.split(' ')
result = ' '.join((tmp[1], tmp[0]))
```

Comment: OP clearly hasn't tried, you shouldn't just give them the answer. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: wow someones angry, I'm new relax.

Comment: Skill level has no bearing on effort/research as this question has been asked and answered previously.

Comment: Damn, you lot are aggressive haha. Chill out boys.

Comment: The last line should use tmp, not s. Also, this will only work for 2-word strings.